# Doubt regarding orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

While studying inner product space I came across a theorem that is if V is an inner product space and $\{x_1,x_2,.....x_n\}$ be the orthonormal set of nonzero vectors. Then if $y\in V$ then $ y=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} <y,x_i>x_i$.

Now my doubt is if there are two different inner product space, can $y$ be written as in two different combination of that same element that is $\{x_1,x_2,.....x_n\}$ is orthonormal set of elements for the second inner product space also.

If what I am stating is true, then it will be great if someone can provide me an example proving my claim. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $x_i$ are orthonormal, then they are linearly independent, so there is at most one way to represent $y$ as a linear combination of them, regardless of what inner product you use.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning my doubt. Can it be proven if a set is linear independent then it must be orthogonal by at least one inner product. Because I am thinking inner product space may divide basis of a certain vector space in different classes not necessarily disjoint

Comment: Given any linearly independent set in a finite dimensional vector space, you can use it to define an inner product with respect to which it will be an orthogonal set. .

Comment: If $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ is linearly independent we can define $ \langle \sum a_ix_i, \sum b_ix_i \rangle =\sum a_ib_i$ to define an inner product which makes $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ orthonormal.

Comment: @Kavi, that only defines the inner product on the space spanned by the $x_i$, which may not be the whole space. Perhaps OP meant for the $x_i$ to be a basis, but this is nowhere stated.

Comment: If you have any further questions about my answer, 631697, please ask. If you find I have fully answered your question, you have the option of "accepting" it by clicking in the check-mark next to it.